# Is there a way to abstract multiple useState expressions into a separate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Supposing I have a React component with a large number of form inputs. Each of those inputs needs to map to state such that that information can be then used to create a large payload.

Is there a way to take something like the following:

```
const [formFieldExample1, setFormFieldExample1] = useState();
const [formFieldExample2, setFormFieldExample2] = useState();
// etc
```

... and condense it into a single expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an object as state?

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState({});
```

Then in your change handler

```
const changeHandler = (event) =>{  
   setFields(previous => {  
       return {...previous, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't move the states to separate files because of the hook lifecycle.

The best way to do what you want to do is one state with many fields:

```
const [form, form] = useState({
    field1: '',
    field2: '',
});
```

Another way to do it, is by using [Formik](https://formik.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object, and use a small function to easily update your form.

```js
const [form, setForm] = useState({username:"", password:""});
const changeForm = (value,field)=> { setForm(prev => {...prev,[field]:value})}
```